# Uncaught Error: Invariant failed: A state mutation was detected between dispatches, in the path 'oidc.user.profile.amr.randomItem'

Tags: reactjs, .net, react-redux

I'm getting errors on Google Chrome while running my React app.
It occurs when webpack hot dev server reloads the page after editing the code or when i hit `F5` and a workaround i could find was to open my app in a new tab.

first error message

```
    Uncaught Error: Invariant failed: A state mutation was detected between dispatches, in the path 'oidc.user.profile.amr.randomItem'.  This may cause incorrect behavior. (https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-mutate-state)
        at invariant (:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:222849)
        at :3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:223003
        at Object.measureTime (:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:222771)
        at Object.dispatch (:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:222999)
        at dispatch (<anonymous>:14608:80)
        at :3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:67534
        at commitHookEffectListMount (:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:426181)
        at commitPassiveHookEffects (:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:426218)
        at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:406763)
        at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:406812)
        at invokeGuardedCallback (:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:406865)
        at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:429282)
        at unstable_runWithPriority (:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:472885)
        at runWithPriority$1 (:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:417650)
        at flushPassiveEffects (:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:429250)
        at performSyncWorkOnRoot (:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:428165)
        at :3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:417704
        at unstable_runWithPriority (:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:472885)
```

Second error

```
    The above error occurred in the <BoardDetails> component:
        in BoardDetails (created by Context.Consumer)
        in Route (at BoardPage.tsx:9)
        in BoardPage (created by Context.Consumer)
        in Route (at PrivatePage.tsx:33)
        in Switch (at PrivatePage.tsx:30)
        in div (at PrivatePage.tsx:28)
        in div (at subMain.components.tsx:14)
        in div (at subMain.components.tsx:13)
        in SubMain (at PrivatePage.tsx:27)
        in Unknown (at RouteGuard.tsx:7)
        in Route (at Routes.tsx:39)
        in Switch (at Routes.tsx:27)
        in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
        in BrowserRouter (at Routes.tsx:26)
        in RoutesWrapper (at main.tsx:20)
        in div (at main.tsx:19)
```

The file to which is pointing the error

```js
    import React, { Suspense } from "react";
    import { useBoardWrapperStyles } from "./BoardWrapper.styles";
    import { EditPanelWrapper } from "../shared/editPanel/editPanel.component";
    import { useRoutingParams } from "../../routes/useRoutingParams";
    import { useUpdateLastVisitedBoard } from "../../hooks/useUpdateLastVisitedBoard";
    import { useViewSubscription } from "../../subscriptions/useViewSubscription";
    
    const ViewWrapper: React.LazyExoticComponent<any> = React.lazy(() => import("../view/ViewWrapper"));
    
    const BoardDetails: React.FC = () => {
      const classes = useBoardWrapperStyles();
      const boardId = useRoutingParams("board");
      useViewSubscription();
      useUpdateLastVisitedBoard(boardId);
      return (
        <>
          <EditPanelWrapper page="View" />
          <div className={classes.root}>
            <div className={classes.boardContent}>
              <Suspense fallback={null}>
                <ViewWrapper />
              </Suspense>
            </div>
          </div>
        </>
      );
    };
    
    export default React.memo(BoardDetails);
```

another related file

```js
    import React from "react";
    import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
    import BoardDetails from "../components/board/BoardWrapper.component";
    import { RoutesMap } from "./routing.utils";
    
    export const BoardPage: React.FC<{}> = () => {
      return (
        <>
          <Route path={[RoutesMap.boardEditPanelPage.path, RoutesMap.boardPage.path]} component={BoardDetails} />
        </>
      );
    };
```

The redux action dispatch causing the error is made in this file

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Subscriptions } from "../../features/serverDataState/generated/Subscriptions";
import { updateSubscriptions } from "../../services/subscriptions/updateSubscriptions";
import IFrontAppState from "../redux-store/IApplicationState";

// Hook to use in page root component
// return true if readModels are ready
export const useReadModels = (subscriptions: Subscriptions): boolean => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(updateSubscriptions(subscriptions));
  }, [dispatch, subscriptions]);
  const isDone = useSelector((store: IFrontAppState) => {
    return (
      store.serverDataState.synchronized &&
      store.serverDataState.currentSubscriptions === store.serverDataState.queriedSubscriptions &&
      Object.keys(store.idleState.serverCommandsWaiting).length === 0
    );
  });
  return isDone;
};
```

The function being called in the useReadModels component

```
export const updateSubscriptions = (subscriptions: Subscriptions): AppThunk => async (
  dispatch: AppDispatch,
  getState: () => IFrontAppState
) => {
  if (SubscriptionsAreEquals(getState().serverDataState.queriedSubscriptions, subscriptions)) {
    return;
  }
  dispatch(setQueriedSubscription(subscriptions));
  cancelTokenSource.cancel();
  await lastCallPromise;
  await postSubscriptions(dispatch, getState);
};
```

and the setQueriedSubscription function's code

```
const serverDataStateSlice = createSlice({
  name: "serverDataState",
  initialState: initialServerDataState,
  reducers: {
    setQueriedSubscription: (draft: Draft<ServerDataState>, action: PayloadAction<Subscriptions>) => {
      draft.queriedSubscriptions = action.payload;
    },
    updateServerDataState: (
      draft: Draft<ServerDataState>,
      action: PayloadAction<{
        command: UpdateSubscriptionsCommandPayload;
        response: UpdateSubscriptionsCommandResponse;
      }>
    ) => {
      draft.synchronized = false;
      draft.currentSubscriptions = draft.queriedSubscriptions;
      delete draft.erroredSubscriptionsCommandPayload;
      updateServerReadModelsRepositories(draft.ReadModels, action.payload.command, action.payload.response);
    },
    updateLastAppliedEventsFromServerState: (draft: Draft<ServerDataState>, action: PayloadAction<void>) => {
      updateLastAppliedEventsFromServerStateImpl(draft);
    },
    onLocalStateSynchronized: (draft: Draft<ServerDataState>, action: PayloadAction<void>) => {
      draft.synchronized = true;
    },
    onSubscriptionsCallError: (
      draft: Draft<ServerDataState>,
      action: PayloadAction<UpdateSubscriptionsCommandPayload>
    ) => {
      delete draft.queriedSubscriptions;
      draft.erroredSubscriptionsCommandPayload = action.payload;
    },
    resetServerDataState: (draft: Draft<ServerDataState>, action: PayloadAction<void>) => {
      draft.synchronized = false;
      draft.currentSubscriptions = {};
      draft.queriedSubscriptions = {};
      delete draft.erroredSubscriptionsCommandPayload;
      draft.ReadModels = createInitialServerReadModelsRepositories();
    },
    insertServerPendingEvent: (draft: Draft<ServerDataState>, action: PayloadAction<DomainEvent>) => {
      draft.synchronized = false;
      const event = action.payload;
      const pendingEvents = draft.pendingDomainEvents[event.AggregateType];
      const id = event.AggregateId;
      pendingEvents[id] = pendingEvents[id] || [];
      const events = pendingEvents[id];
      let position: number | null = null;
      for (let i = events.length; i > 0 && position === null; i--) {
        if (events[i - 1].AggregateSequenceNumber < event.AggregateSequenceNumber) {
          position = i;
        }
      }
      position = position || 0;
      events.splice(position, 0, event as any);
    },
    applyServerPendingEvents: (draft: Draft<ServerDataState>, action: PayloadAction<void>) => {
      Object.keys(draft.pendingDomainEvents).forEach(aggregateType => {
        Object.keys(draft.pendingDomainEvents[aggregateType]).forEach(aggregateId => {
          const events = draft.pendingDomainEvents[aggregateType][aggregateId] as DomainEvent[];
          events.forEach(domainEvent => {
            // console.log("working on event ", domainEvent.Type);
            // const ce = current(domainEvent);
            // console.log("ce", ce);
            // if (!AssertInvariants(draft.ReadModels)) {
            //   console.error("INVARIANTS ERROR BEFORE apply event", current(domainEvent), current(draft.ReadModels));
            // }
            ServerDomainEventHandler(draft.ReadModels, domainEvent, draft.currentSubscriptions);
            // if (!AssertInvariants(draft.ReadModels)) {
            //   console.error("INVARIANTS ERROR AFTER apply event", current(domainEvent), current(draft.ReadModels));
            // }
            const oldLast =
              draft.lastAppliedEvents[domainEvent.AggregateType] &&
              draft.lastAppliedEvents[domainEvent.AggregateType][domainEvent.AggregateId];
            if (oldLast || oldLast === 0) {
              const newLast =
                domainEvent.AggregateSequenceNumber > oldLast ? domainEvent.AggregateSequenceNumber : oldLast;
              draft.lastAppliedEvents[domainEvent.AggregateType][domainEvent.AggregateId] = newLast;
            }
          });
        });
      });
      draft.pendingDomainEvents = createInitialPendingDomainEvents();
    }
  }
});
```

What I wonder the most is why it does happen only in google chrome and not in Firefox, (I tired reinstall it but in vain) and why it occurs only in the current tab after it reloads but not when reopen the same url in another tab in the same browser's window.

The error is related to "oidc.user.profile.amr.randomItem" which is related to the app backend made with .NET (which I don't know much, I just can deal with the front end of the app)

I noticed that some chrome extensions seems to be responsible for the error when they are activated (Google Sheet is one of them). I tried to disactivate them all and now the error is gone. But I wish i can avoid the error even when those extensions are active.

Comment: It suggests that you have dispatched a redux action and mutated the state in the reducer/middleware, none of such code is posted in your question so I cannot point out where that happens.

Comment: @HMR I'm going to update the question, i found where the action dispatch is happening